# how to run javascript function after location.reload() in same browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple function;

```
    setTimeout(function(){ alert('hello');  
         //Business stuffs..
         location.reload();
         eval(localStorage.getItem('mysc'))},5000)
```

after open in a browser(chrome or firefox) I type this;

```
localStorage.setItem("mysc","setTimeout(function(){ 
    //Business stuffs...
    location.reload();
    eval(localStorage.getItem('mysc'))
    },5000)");
```

After that once I type;

```
eval(localStorage.getItem('mysc'))
```

I want this function executes in same browser window forever.. or till close the browser..
but as you guess, it only works once. 
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: `setInterval(function() { eval(localStorage.getItem('mysc')) })`

Comment: @adeneo let me try it :)

Comment: you want first 5 sec wait then forever or call function every 5 sec ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're doing, or why? Why would you store javascript in localstorage just to execute on the next reload ?

Comment: @adeneo not work, dont call after reload..

Comment: @Mahi call function every 5 sec, yes but there is a location.reload() function that makes this a bit tricky..

Comment: @adeneo what I am doing is clear; runing javascript function which call himself even after page reload.. this goes on till browser closed

Comment: This seems very unorthodox - why do you need to do this?

Comment: @ForeignObject I need check if current page contains specific keyword if yes I will post it to remote db with ajax all imlementation should be in clientside.. actually this is not possible anyway in backend with any PL

Comment: @TyForHelpDude if you want to call function every 5sec then sure use setInterval

Comment: @Mahi but interval stops after location reload... if I comment out it works fine but refresh page is mandotory

Comment: You can't execute javascript on the current page, even in a timeout, that keeps executing after a page reload, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the timer *on page load*, and reload the page in the callback. When the page reloads, the timer will be re-created. This will "recursively" reload the page every 5 seconds.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log('page loaded, waiting...');
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('reloading');
        location.reload();
      }, 5000);
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

---

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this if you don't control the page you want to reload (i.e., using Dev Tools or console APIs). It's impossible to attach a script to execute on the next page load, and any active timers are cleared when the current page unloads. A browser extension is probably the way to go; for example, [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can be used to achieve this in Chrome.

Comment: vaiow it looks what I am looking for.. let me try

Comment: Note that you can't accomplish this from the dev tools, since you need a script to automatically execute on every page load.

Comment: yeah this is why I dont accept this.. because I need this work in console..

Comment: I need find a way trig this iteration in dev console

Comment: Please update your question with this requirement. This will probably require hooking into some console API, and if it even exists, it will be different for every browser. This is a job for a browser extension, not a console script.

Comment: your last comment more close to my answer in the post, i already made search and I though I need to develop plugin for browser ? can you eloborate your answer with this detail and if you know more please detail it

Comment: Sorry, I've never written a browser extension. A quick search brings up [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for Chrome, looks like what you need. In other browsers, it will be something else.

Comment: okey can you edit your answer including your last comments about the topic here, then its makes more sense about my case